# Where does CGI.pm normally create temporary files?

Tags: perl, cgi, activestate

On all my Windows servers, except for one machine, when I execute the following code to allocate a temporary files folder:

```
use CGI;
my $tmpfile = new CGITempFile(1);
print "tmpfile='", $tmpfile->as_string(), "'\n";
```

The variable `$tmpfile` is assigned the value `'.\CGItemp1'` and this is what I want. But on one of my servers it's incorrectly set to `C:\temp\CGItemp1`.

All the servers are running Windows 2003 Standard Edition, IIS6 and ActivePerl 5.8.8.822 (upgrading to later version of Perl not an option). The result is always the same when running a script from the command line or in IIS as a CGI script (where scriptmap `.pl` = `c:\perl\bin\perl.exe "%s" %s`).

How I can fix this Perl installation and force it to return '`.\CGItemp1`' by default?

I've even copied the whole Perl folder from one of the working servers to this machine but no joy.

[@Hometoast:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86175/where-is-cgi-pm-supposed-to-create-temporary-files/86200#86200)

I checked the '`TMP`' and '`TEMP`' environment variables and also `$ENV{TMP}` and `$ENV{TEMP}` and they're identical.

From command line they point to the user profile directory, for example:

> `C:\DOCUME~1\[USERNAME]\LOCALS~1\Temp\1`

When run under IIS as a CGI script they both point to:

> `c:\windows\temp`

In registry key `HKEY_USERS/.DEFAULT/Environment`, both servers have:

> `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp`

The ActiveState implementation of `CGITempFile()` is clearly using an alternative mechanism to determine how it should generate the temporary folder.

[@Ranguard:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86175/where-is-cgi-pm-supposed-to-create-temporary-files/86993#86993)

The real problem is with the `CGI.pm` module and attachment handling. Whenever a file is uploaded to the site `CGI.pm` needs to store it somewhere temporary. To do this `CGITempFile()` is called within `CGI.pm` to allocate a temporary folder. So unfortunately I can't use `File::Temp`. Thanks anyway.

[@Chris:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86175/where-is-cgi-pm-supposed-to-create-temporary-files/86874#86874)

That helped a bunch. I did have a quick scan through the `CGI.pm` source earlier but your suggestion made me go back and look at it more studiously to understand the underlying algorithm. I got things working, but the oddest thing is that there was originally no `c:\temp` folder on the server.

To obtain a temporary fix I created a `c:\temp` folder and set the relevant permissions for the website's anonymous user account. But because this is a shared box I couldn't leave things that way, even though the temp files were being deleted. To cut a long story short, I renamed the `c:\temp` folder to something different and magically the correct '`.\`' folder path was being returned. I also noticed that the customer had enabled FrontPage extensions on the site, which removes write access for the anonymous user account on the website folders, so this permission needed re-applying. I'm still at a loss as to why at the start of this issue `CGITempFile()` was returning `c:\temp`, even though that folder didn't exist, and why it magically started working again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name of the temporary directory is held in `$CGITempFile::TMPDIRECTORY` and initialised in the `find_tempdir` function in CGI.pm.
The algorithm for choosing the temporary directory is described in the CGI.pm documentation (search for **-private_tempfiles**).
IIUC, if a C:\Temp folder exists on the server, CGI.pm will use it. If none of the directories checked in `find_tempdir` exist, then the current directory "." is used.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Not the direct answer to your question, but have you tried using [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Temp/)?

It is specifically designed to work on any OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this script as you, check the %TEMP% environment variable to see if if it differs.

If IIS is executing, check the values in registry for TMP and TEMP under
HKEY_USERS/.DEFAULT/Environment